# Nuitka - Running ‘main.bin’ outputs nothing when output is expected

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, nuitka

I am working on converting my python code to an executable format using Nuitka. My project consists of a root with a few .py files. There is then one subdirectory with some of my own developed python modules that all the root .py files call.

Reading the documentation, I gathered that running “nuitka —-follow-imports main.py” should work. And it does, no errors. But when I go to run it nothing outputs. I have several print statements and debug logs that should be outputting.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Compiled code with multiple directories using “Nuitka —-follow-imports main.py”

Ran main.py on system and there was no output or any log files written to.